# Concurrency Issue (race condition)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, merge, prepared-statement

I am not even sure how to title this question

I have the following method which works fine but there is a race condition here the problem as  follow:

There is a unique constraint on mobile_number in MSISDN table.

If MULTIPLE (two or more) uploads are submitted which contain the SAME mobile number AND it does NOT exist in the MSISDN table AND the submission is picked up by the upload workers at the SAME time the following MERGE will fail for the last one who trys to commit.

My question is how to fix the above problem?

I have an option of retry if failed once or remove the unique constraint on mobile_number. But I am looking for a better solution. the code as follow:

```
protected static void batchInsertIntoMSISDN(DBAccessor dba, String tablename) throws Exception {

        logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("batch insert into MSISDN STARTED for tableName %s", tablename));

        String sql = "MERGE INTO MSISDN M\n"+
                "      USING  "+tablename +" s\n " +
                " ON (m.mobile_number = s.mobile_number) \n"+
                " WHEN NOT MATCHED \n"+
                "   THEN \n"+
                "       INSERT ( m.id, m.mobile_number,m.state,m.created_date,m.state_updated_date,m.carrier_id ) \n"+
                "       VALUES (MSISDN_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,s.mobile_number,'ACTIVE',SYSDATE,SYSDATE,s.carrier_id) where s.mobile_number is not null \n";

        Connection connection = dba.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        try {
            logger.info("SQL :: "+sql);
            int resultCount = stmt. executeUpdate();

            logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Merge into MSISDN SUCCEEDED (%d rows) for tableName %s", resultCount, tablename));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, String.format("Merge into MSISDN FAILED for tableName %s", tablename), ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            if (stmt != null){
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What's the isolation level? read commited? It fail why tries to insert a already inserted row or it enters in deadlock state or table is locked out?

Comment: it is throwing java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint. That is the thing it doesn't know the mobile_number already exist as normally the commit happen when they try to exit the method

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve your problem is using a code like this:

```
String sql = "MERGE INTO MSISDN M\n"+
            "      USING  (SELECT mobile_number, carrier_id FROM "+ tablename +" GROUP BY mobile_number, carrier_id) s\n " +
            " ON (m.mobile_number = s.mobile_number) \n"+
            " WHEN NOT MATCHED \n"+
            "   THEN \n"+
            "       INSERT ( m.id, m.mobile_number,m.state,m.created_date,m.state_updated_date,m.carrier_id ) \n"+
            "       VALUES (MSISDN_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,s.mobile_number,'ACTIVE',SYSDATE,SYSDATE,s.carrier_id) where s.mobile_number is not null \n";
```

I don't know how Carrier Id are assigned, but if you always have one combination of mobile_number and carrier_id, you won't have problems with duplicates with this code.

If it's possible to receive different combinations of mobile_number and carrier_id, then you must work on your application rules, I mean ¿what Carrier Id would you want to save? ¿why?, ¿what rules will manage this decision?

This can guide you to decide your code.

Comment: Thanks Omar 99% of the time the carrier Id will be the same and default carrier Id will be used